# Explain this part of code, poker deck class

Tags: java, project

I am trying to learn how to make a poker game, so i searched around websites for poker projects.

This is the deck class i found.

This is the part of the code that make no sense to me.

```
   int index_1, index_2;


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        index_1 = generator.nextInt(cards.size() - 1);

        index_2 = generator.nextInt(cards.size() - 1);



        temp = cards.get(index_2);

        cards.set(index_2, cards.get(index_1));

        cards.set(index_1, temp);

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like a random shuffle to me.

Comment: Looks like a really bad shuffle. Google "Fisher-Yates" to see how to do it correctly. I'd love to give you correct code, but the powers that be froze this question, so I'm not allowed to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a random shuffle of the deck, picks two card positions at random. The [`nextInt(cards.size() - 1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) will generate a random index in `[0,cards.size() - 1)` range:

```
index_1 = generator.nextInt(cards.size() - 1);
index_2 = generator.nextInt(cards.size() - 1);
```

swap the two cards, since you have to replace one of the cards first and you don't want to lose that object, the code uses `temp` to hold the first card to be replaced, `cards.get(index_2)` will obtain the first card object.

```
temp = cards.get(index_2);
```

The first `set` will replace the object in `index_2` will the object from `index_1` and the second `set` will replace the object in `index_1` with the temporary object we stored earlier:

```
cards.set(index_2, cards.get(index_1));
cards.set(index_1, temp);
```

It does this procedure `100` times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

If we assume `cards.size() - 1` is the index of the last card in the deck, the `nextInt` call will skip the last card though, hard to know if that was intentional without more context.

Comment: could you explain the swap the two cards:

Comment: @pur3extrme Updated, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What this code is doing is it's swapping two cards in the deck. It does this 100 times arbitrarily. A better way to do this is to randomly assign a card to a position in a deck. The way it is right now may never touch certain groups of cards and you may end up with a clump of cards in the same order as before in the same position. Plus it would only involve 52 moves instead of 300 (card2 -> temp, card1 -> card2, temp -> card1 ).